# How do I set up a child-theme without using @import

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I've always used @import for the css in my child-theme which i'm now told is bad practice.

What is the best way to set up a child theme going forward?  The latest solution on the wordpress codex seems really complex / highly confusing?

There must be a way to do a relatively simple enqueue in my child-theme's functions.php surely?

Any help would be awesome. I feel completely lost / useless trying to find any succinct info on this.

Emily

Comment: can you point out the part that is confusing in the codex instructions? you can just copy the `my_theme_enqueue_styles` function and change the parent theme name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that is in [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#How_to_Create_a_Child_Theme) for queuing the style of the parent theme instead of using `@import`, is not well commented, so i will comment it more, so you have this:

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parent_style = 'parent-style';
    wp_enqueue_style($parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('child-style', 
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', 
            array($parent_style), 
            wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
            );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles');
?>
```

1.- line:

```
$parent_style = 'parent-style';
```

this is literally a string name that you are giving to the theme stylesheet, it will be the `$handle` of the stylesheet you are queuing, it can be what you want, by example `'divi-style'`, in the `HTML` it will be used as the `ID` like this `<link rel="stylesheet" id="divi-style" ...`

2.- line:

```
wp_enqueue_style($parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
```

its registering the stylesheet and queuing it, when its registering it, it will use the name of the first parameter in this case it will be `'parent-style'`, also its using `get_template_directory_uri()` to get the path to the `parent theme` stylesheet.

3.- line:

```
wp_enqueue_style('child-style', 
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', 
            array($parent_style), 
            wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
            );
```

this is registering and queuing the child theme stylesheet (the current theme stylesheet), this is the usual procedure for a theme, each parameter its already explained [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/), for the example:

- `'child-style'` - this is the name of this stylesheet the `$handle`
- `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css'` - this is the path to
  the stylesheet file.
- `array($parent_style)` - this is the array of stylesheets that we need
     to run before our stylesheet runs we cant put actual paths that is
     why we name them with a `$handle`, in this case we need the parent stylesheet to run first (its a dependency)
- `wp_get_theme()->get('Version')` - this is the number version that
  will be at the end of the stylesheet `URL` like this `/style.css?ver=1.0`, this is for cache purposes, the standard is that you update the version so the latest file is loaded and not a cached version, you dont want to change that number in all the files where you use it right? so use `wp_get_theme()->get('Version')` it will get the version that is in your `style.css` file (not the parent one).

so if you want the resumed version it will be like this:

```
<?php

function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    //load the parent stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    //load the child stylesheet but after the parent stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( 'parent-style' ));

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

Comment: David that is a wonderful answer and if I could, I would give you double points !!

Comment: I've just noticed on my site where this is installed it created 2 stylesheets? In other words, all the CSS show's twice in the Chrome developer tools. When I remove the second wp_enqueue_style that has the handle 'child-style', it does what it should, and only produces one stylesheet (i.e. the CSS only shows once in dev tools).  I think the Wordpress codex may have an error in it?

Comment: if you check in the head, there are more than 1 of the same stylesheet being loaded?

Comment: It looks like it.  Can I attach an image to a comment?  It's a localhost site so I can't share a link.  It's showing 'parent-style-css',  'child-style-css' and 'divi-style-css' stylesheets in the head section in the page source code. Divi is the theme I'm using obviously.

Comment: shouldnt be only the parent style  `divi-style-css` and child style `child-style-css`? seems like 1 is additional, which one is `parent-style-css`?

Comment: what do you mean by which is parent-style-css? Its surely the one in the above code?  This is the code I've used: 
`function enqueue_main_childtheme_styles() {
  $parent_style = 'parent-style';

  wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style )
  );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_main_childtheme_styles' );`

Comment: This article seems to explain what is going on.  [link] https://digwp.com/2016/01/include-styles-child-theme/ I don't need the second 'child-style' by the look of things.

Comment: you need to load your child style that is the main file in a WP Theme, what i am seeing that is happening is that the Divi theme has his own function for loading his own stylesheet and it must have his own handler, in the example we are loading the parent style again in the case of Divi as parent.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean David?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55074/discussion-between-david-lee-and-emily-chewy).

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the specific code you're looking for, this can be found in the WordPress Codex [How to Create a Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#How_to_Create_a_Child_Theme)

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
  // This is the parent style handle name. Recommended to leave as it is.
  $parent_style = 'parent-style';

  wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style ),
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
  );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

**Credits** goes to WordPress Codex.

Comment: Oh, so do I just leave $parent_style as 'parent-style'.  That was what was confusing me.  Also do i need to have the wp_get_theme() –> ('version') part as well, and if so does this have to match my child theme version number or the parent theme version number?
Many thanks thus far I do appreciate it.